# Python nested `if else` statements are returning errors

Tags: python

I am trying to read **.txt** and **.log** files, search for specific words and return results to a CSV using if statements. How do I open other files to read in if statements?

I ran the part that's giving me the errors on another python file and it worked fine and was able to open and read. So it's not the code itself I don't think. Although I'm fairly new to Python.

When running the below I get the following error.

> latest_file = max(list_of_files, key=os.path.getctime)
>   ValueError: max() arg is an empty sequence"

```
with open('//' + hostName + '/C$/Windows/System32/inetsrv/config/applicationHost.config') as doc:
    lines1 = doc.read()
    if ("logFormat=" + '"W3C"' in lines1):
        list_of_files = glob.glob('//' + hostName + '/C$/inetpub/logs/LogFiles/W3SVC1/*')
        latest_file = max(list_of_files, key=os.path.getctime)
        y = latest_file
        with open(y) as doc1:
```

Comment: the error is telling you that `list_of_files` has no items, double check that your path to the files is constructed properly

Comment: When I used glob.glob, I remmember it was only a list of filenames, I had to concatenate path+file to open them, probably you have the same problem. Debug is your new best friend

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently it was working for most hostnames. I added the try and except statements and caught the errors.